# Организация структуры проекта React/Express (Webpack)

Tags: reactjs, node.js, webpack, express

Как правильно организовать структуру проекта? Например, я буду использовать React и сервер Node.js (express, думаю это не важно)). Куда что складывать? Если у меня spa? Или же много html файлов?